# OpenShift oc rsync takes long time to complete

Tags: rsync, openshift-origin

I'm running the command `oc rsync . POD:/path/to/dir`. `oc rsync` successfully rsyncs my files, but takes minutes to return.

```
sending incremental file list
Gruntfile.js
server.js
<wait for about 1 minute...>
```

Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: How long does it take to return? Is it 1 minute, or more like 5?

Comment: 5. Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/6058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like problem has gone away](http://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/6058)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to run the command with --loglevel=8 to get an idea of what is happening.

You should also make sure you are running with at least origin v1.1.